# Retrieve value from a sorted dictionary with the help of ke in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, hashtable, key-value

I have a Dictionary, which has a hash table, that is, keys are not sorted.

```
Conflicts oConflicts = oClash.Conflicts;
Dictionary<string, string> dConflicts = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Conflict oConflict;  
for (int iLoopC = 1; iLoopC <= oConflicts.Count; iLoopC++)
{
    oConflict = oConflicts.Item(iLoopC);
    if (Math.Abs(oConflict.Value) < 3)
    {
       dConflicts.Add(oConflict.Value.ToString(), oConflict.SecondProduct.ToString());                            
    }
}
```

I have sorted the dictionary by LINQ:

```
var sortedDict = dConflicts.OrderBy(x => x.Value).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

I am new to this. Could someone help me with how to get the value stored in sortedDict using the particular key value? Like the last value using count the array elements.

Comment: When you call `ToDictionary`, it results in a new `Dictionary` which itself is unordered.

Comment: Use `SortedDictionary<K,V>`.

Comment: Well what about `dConflicts["keyValue"]`? See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers

Comment: There is some specialized uses for SortedDictionaries, but.... did you really need a sorted one? to retrieve a Value from a Dictionary for a given key, only do wantedValue = dConflicts[searchedKey];

Comment: @J.Salas Yes the sorted one is needed in ascending order and the last element needs to be collected.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I need ordered dicitionary one in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

This seems that you are only using a Dictionary just to be sure not Adding duplicates, pretty overkill, but hey...

```
var searchedLastElement = dConflicts.OrderBy(x => x.Value).LastOrDefault().Value;
```

yod didn't need the sorted list to be cast again to dictionary only to retrieve the last element

Comment: Or even `OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault()` to avoid iterating twice.

Comment: Thank you @JohnathanBarclay. This is quite helpful.